# patternsearch with more than one variable in matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am using patternsearch function in matlab. And my original code,

```
[para,fv] = patternsearch(@(para)objective(para),para0,[],[], ...
             [],[],par_lb,par_ub,[],options);
```

But now my objective function has multiple inputs, for example, object(x,y,z,para), but x,y,z are given and constant. I still want to optimize over para, in that case, I tried to write

```
[para,fv] = patternsearch(@(para)objective(x,y,z,para),para0,[],[], ...
             [],[],par_lb,par_ub,[],options);
```

But it shows my errors. I am wondering how can I do that?

Comment: You are using anonymous function correctly, so the problem is not in `patternsearch`. What exactly is the error you get?

Comment: @Terry you're very unlikely to get meaningful help until you provide a "Minimal Working Example". Or at *least* the inputs you're using and the errors you're getting ...